# How to add css to a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, css, spring

When I include css it throws an error o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound: No match for GET /css/s.css
In spring sequiriti I have added

```
  .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
```

Link in html:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/s.css}">
```

architecture folders:

```
  -Resources
    -static
       -css
          -s.css
     -templates
       -main
          -home.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add such thing

```
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).